# Is it possible to give a reference to an ArrayList without allowing it to be modified?

Tags: java, arraylist

If I want another class to be able to access the content of an arraylist, for example looping through it to see what's inside without allowing it to actually add or delete any elements, is that possible?

In my mind, I'm thinking there should be some way to send an immutable version of the ArrayList.

If that is possible, can someone show me an example please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plenty of ways...

The simplest would be to wrap your ArrayList in an [unmodifiable list](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList(java.util.List)), using:

```java
Collections.unmodifiableList(yourArrayList)
```

This returns an unmodifiable view of the list.

*Note that this doesn't mean the items themselves cannot be modified.*

Other alternatives could be:

- Converting the list to an array (with `toArray(T[] a)`, and passing that to `Arrays.asList()`, which would also send back an unmodifiable list.
- If using some other libraries in your code, like Guava, you could invoke `ImmutableList.copyOf()` or other variations.